# How can I split string using regular expression in bigquery

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I want to split the field in big query data table.

I give you sample case..

==case 1==
Source Filed= "idx1-cnt1-name1,idx2-cnt2-name2... same pattern"

```
Result table
idx | cnt | name |
idx1,cnt1,name1
idx2,cnt2,name2,....
```

in query:

```
select                      
    regexp_extract(split_col, r'([\d]*)-') as ItemIdx,  
    regexp_extract(split_col, r'-([\d]*)-') as Cnt,
    regexp_extract(split_col, r'-([\d]*)$') as TitleIdx
From (
Select pid,now, split(source field, ',') split_col from (       
SELECT * FROM table ))
```

but I can't make a code this case

this case string has multiple saparator.

==case 2==

Source String = "item1-name1-type1-value1,.... same pattern"

```
Result Table
name | type
name1, type1
name2,type2
```

field count is different.

but just I need second, third field value.

how can I make a query..

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That function is product specific.)

Comment: it is hard reverse engineer what exactly you need - please provide more representative example and expected result for both cases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see you are using BigQuery legacy sql - so below example in it (note  - it is quite recommended to use BigQuery Standard SQL whenever you can - so consider migrating)  - below is simplified to make logic better readable for you so you can easily extend it to potentially more similar cases

Case 1 / example

```
#legacySQL
SELECT                      
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^(.*?)-.*?-.*?$') AS idx,  
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-(.*?)-.*?$') AS cnt,
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-.*?-(.*?$)') AS name
FROM (
  SELECT SPLIT(source_field, ',') split_col 
  FROM (SELECT "idx1-cnt1-name1,idx2-cnt2-name2" source_field)
)
```

result:

```
Row idx     cnt     name     
1   idx1    cnt1    name1    
2   idx2    cnt2    name2
```

Case 2 / example

```
#legacySQL
SELECT                      
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-(.*?)-.*?') AS name,  
    REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-.*?-(.*?)-') AS type
FROM (
  SELECT SPLIT(source_string, ',') split_col 
  FROM (SELECT "item1-name1-type1-value1, item2-name2-type2-value2" source_string)
)
```

result:

```
Row name    type     
1   name1   type1    
2   name2   type2
```

Below is example of same but for BigQuery Standard SQL (just case 2 as they really similar)

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "item1-name1-type1-value1, item2-name2-type2-value2" source_string
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-(.*?)-.*?') AS name,  
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(split_col, r'^.*?-.*?-(.*?)-') AS type
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(SPLIT(source_string, ',')) split_col
```

obviously  - same result

```
Row name    type     
1   name1   type1    
2   name2   type2
```

Yet another option would be  -

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT "item1-name1-type1-value1, item2-name2-type2-value2" source_string
)
SELECT 
  SPLIT(split_col, '-')[SAFE_OFFSET(1)] AS name,  
  SPLIT(split_col, '-')[SAFE_OFFSET(2)] AS type
FROM `project.dataset.table`, UNNEST(SPLIT(source_string, ',')) split_col
```

and so on ...